# Write composite data type to Excel range from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What is a good way of writing large numbers of custom data Type to an Excel worksheet?
eg POINT structure - var(i).X, var(i).Y , var(i).Z

Currently I convert the data type to a normal array eg var2(1 to N, 1 to 3) , and then write the array to worksheet

```
var2(i,1) = var(i).X 
var2(i,2) = var(i).y 
var2(i,3) = var(i).z
```

This is tedious and prone to typos. Is there a better way to write to worksheet?